# How to exclude post formats from wordpress recent posts in a tabs widget

Tags: wp-query, query-posts, post-formats

hey guys so i have a problem is that what i want is just standard recent posts only to show 
and i using a function in my the theme function file to show the recent post 
the code of the function

```
function aya_last_posts($numberOfPosts = 5 , $thumb = true){
global $post;
$orig_post = $post;
$lastPosts = get_posts('numberposts='.$numberOfPosts);
foreach($lastPosts as $post): setup_postdata($post);
?>
<?php if ( function_exists("has_post_thumbnail") && has_post_thumbnail() && $thumb ) : ?>   
   <div class="hole-post">      
    <div class="post-thumbnail">
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php printf( __( 'Permalink to %s', 'aya' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php aya_thumb('aya-medium'); ?><span class="overlay-icon"></span></a>
    </div><!-- post-thumbnail /-->
<?php endif; ?>
    <div class="tabtitle"><h3><a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $post->ID ) ?>" 
title="<?php echo the_title(); ?>"><?php echo the_title(); ?></a></h3></div>

</li>
</div>
<?php endforeach; 
$post = $orig_post;
}
```

and i dint know where i should put the code to exclude the post formats and this is some link that can help
http://wordpress.mfields.org/2011/post-format-queries/
please help guys

the code of my tabs widget

```
<?php
## widget_tabs
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'widget_tabs_box' );
function widget_tabs_box(){
register_widget( 'widget_tabs' );
}
class widget_tabs extends WP_Widget {
function widget_tabs() {
    $widget_ops = array( 'description' => 'Most Popular, Recent, Comments, Tags'  );
    $this->WP_Widget( 'widget_tabs',theme_name .'- Tabbed  ', $widget_ops );
}
function widget( $args, $instance ) {

    if( empty($instance['posts_number']) || $instance['posts_number'] == ' ' || !is_numeric($instance['posts_number'])) $posts_number = 5;
    else $posts_number = $instance['posts_number'];
?>
<div class="widget" id="tabbed-widget">
    <div class="widget-container">
        <div class="widget-top">
            <ul class="tabs posts-taps">
                <li class="tabs"><a href="#tab1"><?php _e( 'Popular' , 'aya' ) ?></a></li>
                <li class="tabs"><a href="#tab2"><?php _e( 'Recent' , 'aya' ) ?></a></li>
                <li class="tabs"><a href="#tab3"><?php _e( 'Comments' , 'aya' ) ?></a></li>
                <li class="tabs" style="margin-left:0"><a href="#tab4"><?php _e( 'Tags' , 'aya' ) ?></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="main-warp">
        <div id="tab1" class="tabs-wrap">
            <ul>
                <?php aya_popular_posts( $posts_number ) ?> 
            </ul>
            </div>
        <div id="tab2" class="tabs-wrap">
            <ul>
                <?php aya_last_posts( $posts_number )?> 
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="tab3" class="tabs-wrap">
            <ul>
                <?php  last_comments( $posts_number );?>
            </ul>


</div>
        <div id="tab4" class="tabs-wrap tagcloud">
            <?php wp_tag_cloud( $args = array('largest' => 8,'number' => 25,'orderby'=> 'count', 'order' => 'DESC' )); ?>
        </div>
     </div> 
    </div>
</div><!-- .widget /-->
```

5 );
        $instance = wp_parse_args( (array) $instance, $defaults ); ?>

```
    <p>
        <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'posts_number' ); ?>">Number of items to show : </label>
        <input id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'posts_number' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'posts_number' ); ?>" value="<?php echo $instance['posts_number']; ?>" size="3" type="text" />
    </p>


<?php
}
```

}
?>

Comment: Why not create your own recent posts widget and modify it as you wish. I really do think you will have more control over your own widget that the default one

Comment: the widget i talk a bout it is a tabs widget so there is more function this is why i prefer work with function

Comment: Then you should [edit] your question and add the correct info. Your title is saying **recent posts widget**

Answer (score 0):

@user6394526 is right...
you cant really exlude post types but you can declare which post types you want to retrieve... See his answer for an example.

The second option which is less preffered (since is would query all posts, even the ones you dont need!) is to check for post type and ignore the one you dont want...

**Using your code:**

```
function aya_last_posts($numberOfPosts = 5 , $thumb = true){
global $post;
$orig_post = $post;
$lastPosts = get_posts('numberposts='.$numberOfPosts);
foreach($lastPosts as $post): setup_postdata($post);

// BUILD POST DATA
$postid     = get_the_id();
$postformat = get_post_format($postid)

    if($postformat != 'post_format_you_dont_want') {
    ?>
    <?php if ( function_exists("has_post_thumbnail") && has_post_thumbnail() && $thumb ) : ?>   
       <div class="hole-post">      
        <div class="post-thumbnail">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php printf( __( 'Permalink to %s', 'aya' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php aya_thumb('aya-medium'); ?><span class="overlay-icon"></span></a>
        </div><!-- post-thumbnail /-->
    <?php endif; ?>
        <div class="tabtitle"><h3><a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $post->ID ) ?>" 
    title="<?php echo the_title(); ?>"><?php echo the_title(); ?></a></h3></div>

    </li>
    </div>
    <?php 
    }

endforeach; 
$post = $orig_post;
}
```

**Hope this helps...**
here is a list of common post formats:

- aside
- chat
- gallery
- link
- image
- quote
- status
- video
- audio

Unless you created a custom one you should the format name you dont want from here
example:

```
if($postformat != 'aside') {
```

Comment: how should i write the post type that i dont want is like this `'postype_link'` or`'post-format-aside'` and thanks for ur effort

Comment: Hmm... your not talking about post format right? but rather about post type (right?) ... if so you should write the post type name like was used when registering it in the function register_post_type... If you didnt write that function you can click add new in your admin and you'll see in the url http://www.example.com/wp-admin/post-new.php?post_type=HERE_WOULD_BE_ITS_NAME

Comment: ohh man.. i see in your title you asked to exclude post formats... fixing my code now.

Comment: ok... fixed that code. now you can screen out undesired post formats.